# Ubuntu hangs when memory is exceeded by large program

Tags: ram, error-handling, parallels

I have been using Ubuntu to run computational simulations of materials. Sometimes calculations overcome total memory available of machine, 64GB RAM, and starts to use swap. When this happen Ubuntu just stop and it is necessary to reboot. Runing the same simulations with linux Slackware it did not happen, instead of that, the simulations that have been stopped and I have an error in terminal, something like that: "segmentation fault". Is It possible to run the simulations in Ubuntu and overcome the problem of Ubuntu's stops, like Slackware?

Thanks.

Comment: getting a segmentation fault isn't really an improvement, that means your program crashed. What you probably want is a way to keep the system usable when the memory is swapping... What sort of hard drive is your swap partition on and how big is it?

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots A segmentation fault is definitely far preferable to having to reboot the whole system. Besides being less severe and easier to recover from, it's also much easier to debug, especially if debug symbols are available for the software.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting segmentation faults when you run your simulation software in one system, and massive slowdown when you run it in another, then your simulation software is not meant to handle not having enough memory. [Any segmentation fault is an indication of a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault), and often bugs that produce segmentation faults are really bugs where [the behavior of code is *undefined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). On different systems it may act in different (wrong) ways.

So:

- If you or someone you work with wrote the simulation software, you should debug it with the hope of improving performance. I'd recommend starting by compiling it with debug symbols (`gcc -g ...`) and debugging interactively (for example, in [`gdb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdb)) on Slackware to produce a [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) of the segmentation fault.

  You should also debug it to find memory leaks. You can use [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), [Boehm GC running in leak detection mode](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/leak.html), or a variety of other tools for this.

  Of course, the most appropriate way to debug it will depend on details of how it works and what language it's written in.
- If you got the simulation software from a totally separate party, you should report a bug. If a debug build or debug symbols are available to you, the bug report would benefit from including a stack trace of the segmentation fault on the Slackware system.

#### There might be some things you can do to terminate the simulation in Ubuntu.

The whole system shouldn't grind to a halt. That is likely to indicate a bug in Ubuntu, possibly in the kernel. Even massive disk I/O should only slow down Ubuntu moderately. You might want to report a bug in Ubuntu's kernel about this.

If you want to do that, [first read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Then you'd start the bug reporting process by running `ubuntu-bug linux` (or if it's a command-line only system, `apport-cli linux`).

**To work around the problem**, you can try limiting available memory by specifying limits in [`limits.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man5/limits.conf.5.html). See also [this blog post](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2011/09/limiting-linux-system-users-limitsconf.html).

In case the problem has something to do with CPU priority, you can run the simulation at a lower priority with [`nice`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/nice.1.html) (e.g., `nice -n 15 command...`) or lower it while running with [`renice`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/renice.1.html).

**If you can use the machine at all** as it slows down and the simulation needs to be stopped (sometimes a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) responds better than the GUI), you can try killing the process with [the `KILL` signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL#SIGKILL) (which is the strongest way to kill a process):

```
kill -KILL command
```

Here *`command`* is just one word, the name of the executable. All executables with that name will be killed (hence "[`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/killall.1.html)"). If you have the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (from [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/ps.1.html)), you can of course run `kill -KILL PID` instead.

Comment: Could the program segfaulted because it was killed by the kernel when running out of memory? (There are several kernel options to deal with programs running out of memory; Ubuntu has the worse defaults I have found -- the system hangs as it tries to swap.)