# Segmentation error whyle trying to install and run Maya 2019 on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: software-installation, permissions, python, 21.10

I'm trying to install Maya 2019 on Ubuntu 21.10. I think I have configured everything correctly and I'm close to make Maya work correctly,but unfortunately at the end I get a segmentation error and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone give me some hint ? Below you can see all the commands that I have issued :

```
apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential zlib1g-dev

add-apt-repository ppa:zeehio/libxp

nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeehio/libxp/ubuntu/ focal main

apt update / apt upgrade

cd /home/john/Downloads/Maya-Linux/Autodesk_Maya_2019_1_Update_Linux_64bit/rpm/

alien -vc adlmapps14-14.0.23-0.x86_64.rpm

alien -vc adlmflexnetclient-14.0.23-0.x86_64.rpm

alien -vc adlmflexnetserver-14.0.23-0.x86_64.rpm

alien -vc Maya2019_64-2019.0-8580.x86_64.rpm

apt install lsb-core

apt-get install ./adlmapps14_14.0.23-1_amd64.deb

apt-get install ./adlmflexnetserver_14.0.23-1_amd64.deb

apt-get install ./adlmflexnetclient_14.0.23-1_amd64.deb

apt-get install ./maya2019-64_2019.0-8581_amd64.deb

alien -vc pcre-utf16-8.42-6.el8.x86_64.rpm

apt install ./pcre-utf16_8.42-7_amd64.deb

cd /home/john/Downloads/Maya-Linux/Autodesk_Maya_2019_1_Update_Linux_64bit/debs/pcre-utf16_8.42-7_amd64/usr/lib64/

cp libpcre16.so.0 /usr/lib

cp libpcre16.so.0 /usr/lib32

cp libpcre16.so.0 /usr/lib64

alien -vc libpng-1.5.13-8.el7.x86_64.rpm

apt install ./libpng_1.5.13-9_amd64.deb

cd /home/john/Downloads/Maya-Linux/Autodesk_Maya_2019_1_Update_Linux_64bit/debs/libpng_1.5.13-9_amd64/usr/lib64/

cp libpng15.so.15 /usr/lib

cp libpng15.so.15 /usr/lib32

cp libpng15.so.15 /usr/lib64

alien -vc compat-openssl10-1.0.2o-3.el8.x86_64.rpm

apt install ./compat-openssl10_1.0.2o-4_amd64.deb

cd /home/john/Downloads/Maya-Linux/Autodesk_Maya_2019_1_Update_Linux_64bit/debs/compat-openssl10_1.0.2o-4_amd64/data/usr/lib64/

cp libcrypto.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib

cp libcrypto.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib32

cp libcrypto.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib64

cp libcrypto.so.10 /usr/lib

cp libcrypto.so.10 /usr/lib32

cp libcrypto.so.10 /usr/lib64

cp libssl.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib

cp libssl.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib32

cp libssl.so.1.0.2o /usr/lib64

cp libssl.so.10 /usr/lib

cp libssl.so.10 /usr/lib32

cp libssl.so.10 /usr/lib64

/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin# sudo systemctl status adsklicensing
● adsklicensing.service - Autodesk Licensing Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/adsklicensing.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-03-26 23:07:45 CET; 18h ago
   Main PID: 881 (AdskLicensingSe)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 4615)
     Memory: 5.0M
        CPU: 22.389s
     CGroup: /system.slice/adsklicensing.service
             └─881 /usr/bin/AdskLicensingService --run

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb_preview.so.2

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.0

ln -s /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng15.so.15

ln -s /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0

export TMPDIR=/home/john/tmp

/usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin# maya

Stack trace:
  pthread_kill
  raise
  abort
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8(+0x2488) [0x7f93712f8488]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(+0xfe4f) [0x7f9338952e4f]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x8ebfb) [0x7f9388596bfb]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(+0xec47) [0x7f9338951c47]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so(+0xecc9) [0x7f9338951cc9]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xae395) [0x7f93885b6395]
  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
  PyEval_EvalCodeEx
  PyEval_EvalCode
  PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x14b30e) [0x7f938865330e]
  PyObject_Call
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x49d61) [0x7f9388551d61]
  PyObject_CallMethod
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112dc1) [0x7f938861adc1]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x113034) [0x7f938861b034]
  PyImport_ImportModuleLevel
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf30af) [0x7f93885fb0af]
  PyObject_Call
  PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords
  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
  PyEval_EvalCodeEx
  PyEval_EvalCode
  PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x14b30e) [0x7f938865330e]
  PyObject_Call
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x49d61) [0x7f9388551d61]
  PyObject_CallMethod
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x112dc1) [0x7f938861adc1]
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x113075) [0x7f938861b075]
  PyImport_ImportModuleLevel
  /usr/autodesk/maya2019/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xf30af) [0x7f93885fb0af]
  PyObject_Call
  PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords
  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
  PyEval_EvalCodeEx

sudo /usr/local/bin/maya: line 188: 142424 Segmentation Error /usr/autodesk/maya2019/bin/maya.bin

Fatal error. Attempting to save in /home/john/tmp/john.20220327.2324.ma
```

**The permissions of the tmp folder are :**

owner = root(root)

access : read and write

group : root

access : read and write

other access : read and write

Comment: This is not an answer:  You may find this not entirely a great subject for this group.  A [segmentation error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault) indicates a problem within the program, or within your hardware. These can be tracked down, but I think debugging a program that's being ported from RPM files might be a bit beyond normal Ubuntu operations!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a segmentation fault?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've been unsuccessful in getting anything lower than Maya 2020 to run in Ubuntu.  Even CentOS8 (which it's SUPPOSED to run on) doesn't work properly.  I can license and run the command, but it just hangs and doesn't ever progress.  Maya 2020, however, is possible to run at least on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.  I'm attempting to install on PopOS 21.1 but I remember in the beginning I tried installing Maya 2020 on Ubuntu 21.10 and it constantly crashed.  I've read about downgrading some libraries to make it work but I've at least got a path to 20.04 running both Maya and Motionbuilder 2020 and above.  If you ever get 2019 to work, please share as it's very elusive to figure out what's going wrong!